# Rally API not retrieving custom values of system fields

Tags: rally

I am using below rally web service to retrieve Environment field values

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/AttributeDefinition/-12511/AllowedValues

It returns system values Development,Test,Staging,Production.

If I add or change Environment field values still web service returns same data.

I want web-service to return newly updated values like Env-2 ,Env-3 etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing, it should be working for you as you want.  Do you go through a proxy (that might be caching the old response)?